# Another word for Business Logic?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

What is another good word for *Business Logic*?

Software might also run in civil service offices or for hobbyists, so I never felt that comfortable with using that term in certain modules and documentation.

*App Logic* is too specific as well, because logic modules might also be used in services.

Comment: So whats all your layers called now? GUI or User-logic?

Comment: @BerggreenDK: DataAccess, DomainLogic, and for MVVM ViewLogic and Views

Comment: DomainLogic doesnt work for me, as I think of DL and DAL as DataLayers, so the prefix will be bad for me. Hmm... gotta think something up myself I guess. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: In many applications, another word for "business logic" is "place we stuffed all the ugly part of the code."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might be able to get away with Domain Logic?

Comment: Yea it is the answer... but business logic designed to represent a concept not a company... i wanted to argue that business logic is the answer... but that would have most def led to negative points ;) ...

Answer (score 4):

**Orchestration Layer** or just **Orchestration**.

Comment: orchestration kind of means a different thing, it may relate to a business process, but nowadays is a little lower level

Answer (score 2):

How about Core logic?  It's exactly what you are referring to with business logic anyway - the core logic of your app

Comment: thanks for the answer, but somehow it doesn't do it for me. ;-) ... I also use `Core` already widely for various kinds of stuff in things that go to the meat :->

Comment: I use both Domain and Core extensively throughout most of my apps :)    I prefer Domain Logic too and gave Nix an upvote, I'll leave my answer here in case someone down the road prefers it

Comment: People might think you're talking about [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) from Clojure.

Comment: @twopoint718 if the target audience of OP is not comfortable with the term "business logic", Clojure or related terminology should hardly matter :)

Comment: core seems too vague for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Workflow / Bussiness workflow / Domain modeling / Bussiness Process

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I want to give 2, admittedly quite opinionated, answers.

1. The word business isn't actually that bad, if you think about the original meaning. Business comes from the work busy. It doesn't actually have anything to do economics, finance, professions or money. This is evident form expressions like "mind your own business", "let's get down to business" or "funny business". So "business" is simply the thing which keeps us, or an application, "busy". However, I do agree that the way the word is used currently often associated with money, so I understand why you would want another word.
2. So to offer an alternative, I like to use "controller". This comes from the "middle layer" of a model-view-cotroller artchitecture. MVC is designed for GUI applications, but IMO the concept can be extended also into other areas and types of applications.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get wild:

- Features
- API
- Functionality
- BL
- Modules
- Core
- Actions
- Commands

all of them are way too broad or not equivalent to "business logic", but you still might want to name a module like this :)